# Execute an action on all classes with an interface implement

Tags: java, interface, listener

I wrote this code and i need create a listener in `Class3` to call all overrides methods of the interface "MethodsListener", how can i accomplish this?

When in `Class3` i call any function of the interface `MethodsListener` i need run this function in all class that implement this interface, in the next example, when i call the function `Method2` in `Class3` i need run `Method2` in `Class1`.

I wrote this code and i need create a listener in `Class3` to call all overrides methods of the interface `MethodsListener`, how can i solve this?.

When in the `Class3` i call to any function of the interface `MethodsListener` i need run this function in all classes that implement this interface, in the next example, when i call the function `Method2` in the `Class3` i need run `Method2` in the `Class1`.

All classes are running in separated threads.

This is the example code:

```
public class Class1 implements MethodsListener {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new Thread(new Class2()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void method1(String message) {
        System.out.println("Method 1 executed, message: " + message);
    }
    @Override
    public void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println("Method 2 executed, message: " + message);
    }
}

public class Class2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Class3()).start();
    }
    /*...*/
}

public class Class3 implements Runnable, MethodsListener {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method1("MSG 1");
        method2("MSG 2");
    }

    @Override
    public void method1(String message) {
        System.out.println("Executing Method 1");
    }
    @Override
    public void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println("Executing Method 2");
    }
}

interface MethodsListener {
    public abstract void method1(String message);
    public abstract void method2(String message);
}
```

In the output of this example i need get:

```
Executing Method 1
Method 1 executed, message: MSG 1
Executing Method 2
Method 2 executed, message: MSG 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you might want this code. For simplicity I have tested all the code in one java file. Just create Class1.java in eclipse or whatever IDE you are using and past the following code. All the three classes and interface should go in the same Class1.java file. Although you can create separate files for each one of them.

```
class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new Thread(new Class3()).start();
    }
}

class Class2 implements MethodsListener {

@Override
public void method1(String message) {
        System.out.println("Method 1 executed, message: " + message);
    }
    @Override
    public void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println("Method 2 executed, message: " + message);
    }
}

class Class3 extends Class2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method1("MSG 1");
        method2("MSG 2");
    }

    @Override
    public void method1(String message) {
         System.out.println("Executing Method 1");
         super.method1(message);
    }
    @Override
    public void method2(String message) {
        System.out.println("Executing Method 2");
        super.method2(message);
    }
}

interface MethodsListener {
    public abstract void method1(String message);
    public abstract void method2(String message);
}
```